# How do i set the increment value of autoincrement in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to develop a system to assign room numbers to tenants of a hostel upon registration, using the auto increment feature of sql.

However, it automatically increases by one after every entry. Because the hostel accommodates four people in one room, I want to change this to 4, so that after every 4 entries I get only one id/room number.

How do I go about this? I am using php and sql. If the autoincrement feature is not possible can you please suggest another way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Better way to do it is take two separate fields for room id and id(primary key-autoincrement for students) and run a php code which will take care of room ids after 4 entries.

Comment: Its basically logical first, you need to prepare your approach first then only it can be implemented using code. there are multiple code possibilities which totally depends on you requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You would need:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment

It works like this:

```
mysql> SET @@auto_increment_increment=4;
```

So when you insert 4 rows, the auto increment column will be:

4,8,12,16

Answer (score 0):

as best of my knowledge you cannot change the steps of auto-increment field. I suggest add another field and write a trigger to update its value based on auto-increment field (auto-increment/4).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `auto_increment` for this - it can't handle a situation where multiple records will share the same number and although you can reset it manually (see below) it's also not designed for a situation where numbers may get reused in a random order.

You could just have a `room_number` field with one of the [mysql integer types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) (e.g. tinyint, smallint, mediumint…) or you could separate your database into two tables, one for people (each of whom have an id) and a second to map those ids to rooms.

However you do it, you'd then write a `select` query to check which room numbers are available *before* you add the person's details to the database.

You may need to read up on relational databases if that doesn't sound very clear.

If you *do* need to reset the auto_increment (sometimes it's nice to do it if you've filled a database with test data which you're about to wipe, and you want the real "production" data to begin at 1) you can use:

```
ALTER TABLE [tablename] AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with autoincrement..
Maybe you can do something like this:

```
//Pseudo code
//First you get the count of the highest id, to see how many users are in the last room.
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id=(SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)

//If the result of the last query is >= 4 then insert the next customer with id +1
```